# Integrate Python Library Spleeter on Android Studio

Tags: python, java, android, spleeter

I want to build an android app based on [Spleeter](https://github.com/deezer/spleeter). But I am not sure which tool to use to bridge the way between Java and Python on Android or whether it is possible or not. I would like anyone to please shed some light onto this. I have researched there are tools for Python to join Java but I don't know if they are suitable for Spleeter library. If anyone has already implemented this, please share your insight.
Kindly suggest some tool to integrate these two platforms or advise if it is possible or not.

Comment: Did you make any headway on this?

Comment: See my answer to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have extended this project of Spleeter_Unofficial_TF20_MobileApp.
https://github.com/VVasanth/Spleeter_Unofficial_TF20_MobileApp/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/tensorflow/android/spleetermobileapp/MainActivity.kt

Here is a working version.
https://github.com/farihachaiti/DoKaraokeAI

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31640052)